# how to escape an anchor tag in html which eval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, escaping

Can you please help in escaping this :

```
 <p><%# Eval("Text") + <a class="story-link" href="<%# GetDocumentUrl() %>" target="_self"><%# Eval("ReadFullStoryTitle") %></a> %>
         </p>
```

I have tried like below but its not working :

```
<p><%# Eval("Text") +  <a class="story-link" href="'<%# GetDocumentUrl() %>'" target="_self"><'%#Eval("ReadFullStoryTitle") %'></a> %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using following:

```
<p><%# Eval("Text") %> <a class="story-link" href='<%# GetDocumentUrl() %>' target="_self"><%#Eval("ReadFullStoryTitle") %></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the data using javascripts `innerText` it will escape them properly.

```html
<p id="data"><script>document.getElementById('data')
           .innerText= '<%# Eval("Text") + <a class="story-link" href="<%# GetDocumentUrl() %>" target="_self"><%# Eval("ReadFullStoryTitle") %></a> %>';</script></p>
```

You can also use css `content` property of after and `::after` as follows

```css
#data::after{
   content: '<%# Eval("Text") + <a class="story-link" href="<%# GetDocumentUrl() %>" target="_self"><%# Eval("ReadFullStoryTitle") %></a> %>';
}
```

```html
<p id="data"></p>
```

Or You can use the code in p tag below which is escaped.

```html
<p>&lt;%# Eval("Text") + &lt;a class="story-link" href="&lt;%# GetDocumentUrl() %&gt;" target="_self"&gt;&lt;%# Eval("ReadFullStoryTitle") %&gt;&lt;/a&gt; %&gt;</p>
```